# Strong convergence and a.e. convergence in Bochner spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Let $u_n \longrightarrow u$ strongly in $L^2(0,T;L^p(\Omega))$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$.

It is known that strong convergence in $L^2$ implies a.e. convergence along a subsequence.

Can I then imply that $u_{n_k}(\cdot, t) \longrightarrow u(\cdot,t) $ strongly in $L^p(\Omega)$ for a.e. $t \in \left[0,T\right]$?

Or are there any problems since I work in a Bochner space?

Comment: Yes, you can. ${}$